# undefined control sequence. \bstctlcite

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, undefined

I just want to change how the URL is displayed in `IEEEtran` style. Therefore I added the following to my bibliography file `Literaturverzeichnis.bib`:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
    CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "3",
    CTLnames_show_etal       = "2",
    CTLname_url_prefix = "\par [Online]. Available:"
```

and in the document I use:

```
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

I always get the error ***Undefined control sequence. \bstctlcite***.

---

Here is a small example just with the packages, some text, a citation and the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, english, ngerman, numbers=noenddot, openany, titlepage, intoc, BCOR=10mm, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
    \blindtext
    \cite{Braggins:Fingerprint_sensing_and_analysis}
    \bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,Literaturverzeichnis}\thispagestyle{empty}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```

And here is the .bib-file:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
    CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "3",
    CTLnames_show_etal       = "2",
    CTLname_url_prefix = "\par[Online]. Available:"
}

@article{Braggins:Fingerprint_sensing_and_analysis,
    author = {Braggins, Don},
    journal = {Sensor Review},
    month = {December},
    number = {4},
    pages = {272--277},
    title = {{Fingerprint sensing and analysis}},
    url = {http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/10.1108/02602280110406909 https://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/10.1108/02602280110406909},
    volume = {21},
    year = {2001}
}
```

Here is the message I get:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: If you made a basic mistake, a sample that shows the problem would help *us* find the error...

Comment: `\bstctlcite` is a command provided by the `ieeetran` document class (`ieeetran.cls`) or by the support package `ieeetrantools`. You load neither of those, so the command is not available to you. You can also find the command defined in http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/

Comment: The `ngerman` package is deprecated, don't load `\usepackage{ngerman}`. You should use `babel` instead: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. If you load the `hyperref` package, you don't need to load the `url` package.

Answer (score 7):

The command `\bstctlcite` is provided by the `ieeetran` document class (`ieeetran.cls`) or by the support package `ieeetrantools`. You load neither of those, so the command is not available to you.

You can load `ieeetrantools` with `\usepackage{ieeetrantools}`, or you take the definition of `\bstctlcite` from `ieeetran.bst` directly

```
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

Additionally, `\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}` must be the first citation in your document, so I suggest you call it directly after the `\begin{document}`.

Your document would then look like (the whole `filecontents` block is just to make the example self-contained, it is not needed in your actual document)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,numbers=noenddot, openany, titlepage, BCOR=10mm, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
    CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "3",
    CTLnames_show_etal       = "2",
    CTLname_url_prefix = "\par[Online]. Available:"
}

@article{Braggins:Fingerprint_sensing_and_analysis,
    author = {Braggins, Don},
    journal = {Sensor Review},
    month = {December},
    number = {4},
    pages = {272--277},
    title = {Fingerprint sensing and analysis},
    url = {http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/10.1108/02602280110406909},
    volume = {21},
    year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
    \blindtext
    \cite{Braggins:Fingerprint_sensing_and_analysis}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,\jobname}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Note that the ULRs were messed up because you can only have one URL in the `url` field. Two URLs are too much.